# Spring boot - Snowflake JDBC - Alter session automatically when application loads

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to connect Snowflake to Spring boot based application. Everything works well however due to some crazy defaults in snowflake, I'm having to deal with the below error:
https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/SAP-BW-Java-lang-NoClassDefFoundError-for-Apache-arrow

I can fire the queries via Spring data JPA but not able to map the results at all. The solution asks for changing the default resultset format from ARROW to JSON:

```
Customer can use this property (jdbc_query_result_format=json) in datasouce property of Application server or session property in application like

Statement = connection.createStatement();
Statement.executeQuery("ALTER SESSION SET JDBC_QUERY_RESULT_FORMAT='JSON'");
```

I'm just wondering how could I achieve that with Spring ie. run the above SQL in the bootstrap period. I'm using Spring data JPA queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter **JDBC_QUERY_RESULT_FORMAT** can be set per account/user/session, therefore if you always want to have **JSON** for that user you can set it directly via Snowflake UI only once:

```
ALTER USER <youruser> SET JDBC_QUERY_RESULT_FORMAT='JSON';
```

This would only impact your user and the account would still have **ARROW** as default. And you wouldn't need to set it at session level all the time.

Comment: This is a programmatic access to Snowflake and not via Snowflake UI. So this would not be possible.

Comment: What I meant was that an accountadmin (or a role with enough permissions) can go via Snowflake UI and do that ALTER once, then your programmatic access doesn't needs an ALTER SESSION anymore.

Comment: What would happen if I restart my application (or redeploy the app)? Will it still remember the settings for the user that I’m using to access snowflake programmatically?

Comment: It has nothing to do with your app, once set via Snowflake UI it will stay like that until you run a new ALTER to reset the value. That means you can restart your app as many times as you want, you can even deploy another app using same user and the setting will still be in effect.

Comment: Thanks that helped. However, I found out the root cause behind the error and this trick is no longer required.

Apparently, it has something to do with heap memory configurations for the applications.

Comment: i would like to only set this on jdbc not in snowflake. is there a way to do that with spring?

Comment: @simbo1905 You can always set it at session level directly from JDBC by running an `ALTER SESSION SET JDBC_QUERY_RESULT_FORMAT='JSON'`

Comment: the whole question is about spring, my comment says ‘spring” so I am wanting a spring specific config or code. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This happens on modern JVMs due to Arrow wanting to do low level memory allocations. It logs to stdout that it wants the JVM to be started with `--add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED`.

The fixes that are good for JDK17 are described on the [Arrow Docs](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/java/install.html) as:

```bash
# Directly on the command line
java --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED -jar ...

# Indirectly via environment variables
env _JAVA_OPTIONS="--add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED" java -jar ...
```

So if you are using intellij/Docker setting the env var of `_JAVA_OPTIONS` to be `--add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED` is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the original issue can be fixed easily by tweaking some memory settings in your applications.

Summarising the solution below:

Increase the heap memory and setting `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize` > 64M by setting the `JAVA_OPTS` property for your application.

The rationale behind this is that Arrow format inherently make use of the available heap memory in order to optimise the large results. Not having enough heap space will lead to the above mentioned error.

I still need to perform more tests to find out the ideal values for heap memory, stack size, and this variable → -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize.

EDIT: Below settings worked:

```
"JAVA_OPTS": "-Xss230k -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=100m -Xmx1800m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1500m"

6 instances of the app running in parallel.

2GB RAM per instance ie. 12GB RAM in total (probably an overkill but it snowflake driver does eat up a lot of ram in general)
```